# Accessing a POSTed JSON File in Web API

Tags: c#, json, file, asp.net-web-api

I have created a Web API service that accepts a POSTed JSON file.  With the service, I want to parse the JSON file using JSON.NET.  I have seen multiple posts on the subject, however, I don't want to save the file to disk.  I want to keep the file in memory, parse the file and dispose of the file in memory.

I'm also using .NET Framework 4.0.

EDIT:  I should be more clear.  When the file is POSTed, it is a file stream. The part I don't know is how to convert the stream to JSON.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        int FileLen;
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {

            string MyString = string.Empty;
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];
            FileLen = postedFile.ContentLength;
            byte[] input = new byte[FileLen];
            System.IO.Stream testStream = postedFile.InputStream;
            testStream.Read(input, 0, FileLen);

            for (int Loop1 = 0; Loop1 < FileLen; Loop1++)
               MyString = MyString + input[Loop1].ToString();

            CurrentRate.JSONSerializer(MyString);
```

}

Comment: Try using a [JsonTextReader](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm). It takes a [StringReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx) which would allow you to keep the contents in memory (had this as an answer and decided it was a bad answer because I did not have time to provide an example :( )

Comment: @BobbyD  Please check my EDIT.

Answer (score -1):

Since JSON.NET has the ability to deserialize a file (converted to a stream) with the following code:

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"<pathToFile>"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    MyObject myObject = (MyObject)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(MyObject));
}
```

By swapping out the stream from `File.OpenText` with something similar to the following

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(<FileByteArrayFromMemory>);
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    MyObject myObject = (MyObject)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(MyObject));
}
```

we never have to deal with an actual file.  There may be a more efficient way to create the `MemoryStream` or you may already have a`Stream` and could initialize the and could skip that step.

EDIT 2: more explicitly showed swapping the `StreamReader`

Comment: Please check out my EDIT.  I'm not opening a file.  Instead the controller accepts the file and converts it to a file stream.

Comment: @user1647160 I added the code to swap out the stream instead of explaining you could replace the `File.OpenText` with a different stream